# How to automatically reload a page after x seconds with form data resubmitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 HTML pages: one that ask the user for input about a topic, and one that pulls Twitter data from the Twitter Streaming API pertaining to that topic. This information, however, changes constantly. When I refresh manually, there's a Pop-up that notifies me that I want to "Confirm Data Resubmission" and when I click "continue", it gives me new information. I want to do this automatically within my code, and do this every 10 seconds.

My HTML page was created in tandem with Flask, and uses the Twitter Bootstrap CSS and JS files. I tried using the `<meta>` way and while it does refresh the page automatically, it does not retain the form data submitted on the previous page.

Is such a thing just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a button which submits this form. Have you thought about subscribing to an onClick event? You can create a callback function and inside it invoke `location.reload();` from window global object.

Comment: To set time interval you may use this    `window.setInterval(function, milliseconds)`  For documentation [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp]

Comment: @Bappasarker that documentation was a huge help. And I think I can apply [@TheOpti](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2977017/theopti)'s answer to different parts of my site as well. I'm going to accept this as my answer

Comment: @Bappasarker Your link is including that closing bracket btw :P

Comment: Sorry , I have put the answer in answer box again. If you get help form this please don't forget to give a positive feedback,@mangoHero1

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
location.reload();
```

and

```
setInterval();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having trouble combining the two. If I do [this](https://gist.github.com/Kalaborative/69677e384a107dbf5ed92ebea98f89a7) my page reloads instantly and endlessly...

Comment: Ah,  nevermind. Got it work now. Wasn't getting the function part right. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To set time interval you may use this `window.setInterval(function, milliseconds)`  For documentation

> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp